# Is There a Specific File Structure/Naming Convention for Partials in Stylus?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, stylus

I was wondering if there was any particular naming convention for partials in Stylus.

So, for example, in SASS you might have something like: `@import "headers/_default-header.scss"` or something to that effect. A partial denotes that a) it should not be compiled as its own and b) it is meant as a dependency for another file.

However, in Stylus there doesn't seem to be any particular naming convention for this. Is there any that are de facto standard or should I stick with just naming them similarly to all other files, despite potential confusion?

Answer (score 0):

Good question :) It looks like people are using it like sass. Using prefix underscore for partial and hyphen for splitting words just like your example `_default-header.styl`